# DialogCellEditor: How to fire event on changes/mark the property as changed?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a class, which extends *PropertyDescriptor* and it shall open a small dialog for value input.
It works so far, the dialog is shown and I can enter all values. But the system doesn't show, that the file was edited.

The dialog is a copy of the *InputDialog*.

I have tried to use methods like `fireApplyEditorValue`, `fireEditorValueChanged` and `valueChanged`. But it makes no difference.
I have checked the listeners, which can found in the fire methods and they are the same listeners, which are used by the *TextCellEditor*.

I can't figure out, what I have missed.

Thanks for any advices.

Here is my `createPropertyEditor` method:

```
public CellEditor createPropertyEditor(Composite parent) {
    CellEditor editor = new DialogCellEditor(parent) {
        @Override
        protected Object openDialogBox(Control cellEditorWindow) {
            SimpleDialog dialog = new SimpleDialog(cellEditorWindow.getShell(), (SomeValue) doGetValue());
            dialog.open();
            return dialog.getValue();
        }
    };
    if (getValidator() != null)
        editor.setValidator(getValidator());
    return editor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake.
I have to overwrite the method `equals` in my class *SomeValue*.